# Converting into csv in R

Tags: r, dataframe, csv

I coverted a .txt file in unix to .csv file just by renaming it and My file looks containing 5 columns looks like this

```
X3.148653596.3.148653596_T_C.0.00486129.0.000314907
1  3\t148988533\t3:148988533_G_A\t0.00548803\t1.23281e-05
2   3\t153478699\t3:153478699_T_C\t0.0950017\t0.000391402
3   3\t153504694\t3:153504694_C_T\t0.0303417\t0.000116432
```

How can i convert it to proper csv file in R.

Comment: looks like tab-separated.. `data.table::fread()` (for example) should read this in just fine... Not sure about the col-headers though.. but you can always skip these using the `skip`-argument.

Comment: There is a problem with the first line so you will probably have to skip it. The rest of the lines are tab-separated so you should be able to load it with `read.table()`. See the manual page for details. Then you can use `write.csv()` to create a .csv file.

Comment: @Wimpel i want to convert this tab separated file into csv so it can be readable in excel. i gave it a try but unable to use this command of fread. can you write me some code to adapt.

Comment: Note that just changing the extension of a file does not necessarily change the data within the file. The header binary is the only one changed and this might even lead to a corrupted file. Note that in your case, The problem is that the header is also part of the data. whereby the tab `\t` and colon `:` hve been replaced by  by a `.` and since a variable cannot begin with a number, an `X` has been prepended to the data.  Conside fixing this, or simply maintain your data as `txt` read into R using `read.table()`and use `write.csv()` to write into a csv.

Comment: If you want to read it in Excel, then just open it in Excel. Go to File, Open, and make sure "All files (\*.\*)" is selected as the extension so you can see it. When you go to open this text file, Excel will flash up an import wizard and you can tell it to read tab separated.